# Passing arguments to python script from batch file

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, batch-file, python-3.6

I want to pass arguments from `test.bat` to `myscript.py`.

**`test.bat`**:

```
../path/to/file/myscript.py "myarg1" "myarg2"
```

**`myscript.py`**:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2

import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':

    print sys.version()
    myarg1= sys.argv[1]
    myarg2= sys.argv[2]
```

I am using windows 10 and configured pylauncher as default program to execute python files. I have both python 2.7 and 3.6 in my user and system `PATH` variables. The shebang is taken care and py2.7 interpreter is chosen as expected.

Error I am facing is that the arguments are not passed. Error log reads as below:

```
2.7.15 (v2.7.15:ca079a3ea3, Apr 30 2018, 16:22:17) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\full\path\to\file\myscript.py", line 12, in <module>
myarg1= sys.argv[1]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

One solution:
When I specify `py` in my .bat file it works and arguments are read correctly

```
py ../path/to/file/myscript.py "myarg1" "myarg2"
```

**How can I make this work without adding `py` to my .bat script?**

More info - running these in `cmd` shell:

`assoc .py` gives `.py=Python.File`

`ftype Python.File` gives `Python.File="C:\WINDOWS\py.exe" "%L" %*`

Comment: What happens when you do this.. ? `import sys
 
for arg in sys.argv:
    print('Arg:', arg)` (Obviously format the lines correct.) also, I am unclear of what you mean by _"When I specify py in my .bat file it works and arguments are read correctly"_

Comment: argument printed out only has the python filename. 

I have written the line below that statement. The difference is that I added "py" in the beginning of the line in my .bat script.

Comment: Just the filename? But then you are not passing paramters to it.. Also, just call the script as `python script.py`

Comment: when I add py it works. All arguments are read correctly.

Comment: I want to avoid this adding python or py

Comment: You have to add `py` at the beginning of the command because it's the program that can run the script. Without it, you can't run your script. You can also use `python` instead of `py`

Comment: the last line of code

    py ../path/to/file/myscript.py "myarg1" "myarg2"

Comment: But python is the interpreter, why avoid it? else you would need to set `py` files to always execute using python by associating them with it

Comment: assoc .py and ftype Python.File proves that I have associated pylauncher to .py files

Comment: Is .PY in your PATHEXT environment variable? Can you share the output of running `set PATHEXT` in a command prompt? Here's the output on my machine `PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC;.PY;.PYW` and the batch file works without the py here.

Comment: On my Windows system `ftype Python.File` -> `Python.File="C:\Python\python.exe" "%1" %*` so yours isn't quite right.

Comment: @martineau, it's fine, Windows registry often uses `%L`, which is equivalent to the long file name form of the first parameter. It's probably not that important in this case, as the parameters are being passed to a Win32 or Win64 application, but Win16 applications would otherwise get the short file name.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem when `py` isn't used in the batch file. On Windows, the shebang has no effect unless the script is run via the `py` launcher — so changing it does nothing when running the script directly. The fact that Python 2.7 is being run on your system is likely just because its path appears before the one for Python 3.6 in your `PATH` environment variable. I, too, have both versions installed but only Python 2.7 is in my `PATH` so it's the default. FWIW, I **don't** have `;.PY;.PYW` in my `PATHEXT` environment variable (and adding them didn't change my results).

Comment: Did you by chance use the Context Menu option of "Open With" -> "Choose default program" or some similar action. Check if `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.py\UserChoice` exists. If it does, it can overrule the `ftype` and `assoc` settings. I can reproduce the arguments not being passed if I browse and select `python.exe` as default program. If traced, the entry used is `"...\python.exe "%1"` which is missing the `%*` to capture the arguments. You can delete the `UserChoice` key to return to using the `ftype` and `assoc` settings.

Comment: @michael_heath I did not use context menu option to link the default program.
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.py\UserChoice` exist.

Comment: @JustinEzequiel Here

`PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC;.PY;.PYW`

Comment: @ajayhhh As I mentioned, if the "UserChoice" key exist, delete it. How it was created is not important, that it does exist can be the source of your problem.